# Proper way to page jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to display a number of "dynamic" grids using jqGrid. By dynamic I mean that both definition and data of the grid are retrieved from a database. There are many grids on the page, so I am trying to minimize the number of server trips, and there is a lot of data, so server-side paging is a must.

My workflow is

- On initialization of each grid, retrieve grid definition and first
  page of data in *one* server call.
- If a user sorts/pages, then retrieve a page of data from the server

Because I want to retrieve the grid definition and first page of data in one call, I cannot use datatype: 'json', url: '###' approach; instead I do:

```
grid.jqGrid({
    mtype: 'post',
    ...        
    datatype: function (postdata) {
        if (!init.data) {
            var request = {
                screenId: settings.screenId,
                pageNumber: postdata.page,
                pageSize: postdata.rows,
                sortColumn: postdata.sidx,
                sortDirection: postdata.sortd,
                date: settings.date
            };
            site.callWs("/MyService", request, function (pageResponse) {
                //WHAT TO CALL HERE TO SET A PAGE OF DATA?
            });
        } else {
            //WHAT TO CALL HERE TO SET A PAGE OF DATA?
            init.data = null;
        }
    }
});
```

My data object (pageResponse or init.data) looks like this

[image: Data Object]

I am not sure what method to call on jqGrid once a page of data is returned. I considered addJSONData, but it seems so inefficient to convert JSON back to string, then use EVAL(). Also, considered addRowData or setting the *data* property, but I am confused how to instruct jqGrid that I am doing server-side paging -- if I set the *data* property to one page of records, what do I need to do to tell jqGrid that there is a total of 50 records and this is page 1 out of 10.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't like your approach. Do you tried to implement all just as `datatype: 'json'`? Is it slow? Do you use all jqGrid options correctly? (you can post example of jqGrid definition here). Do you try to use caching of the data (setting `Cache-Control` HTTP headers which corresponds your requirements). I suppose that the solution which you try to implement will *more slowly* (especially if you will use `addRowData`) as the simplest jqGrid implementation with very clear architecture. You should don't forget how many minimal server trips have the page (all separate CSS and JS files etc).

Comment: Oleg, do I understand it correctly that aside from using datatype "json", url: ###" there is no good (fast) way to integrate jqGrid with server-side paging ? If so, I will change my approach to do an extra round-trip. Wanted to avoid it because there may be 10 grids on the page, which may result in a few second delay. Thanks.

Comment: `postdata.page` of `datatype` function has already the information about the requested page. So I see no general problem with implementation of server side paging. What I think is that you can invert many time to optimize first load of the page with all grids, but I suspect that the solution which you will produce will be event slowly as the simplest implementation with multiple asynchronous Ajax requests: one per grid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Can you be so kind to clarify this: if I were to use datatype:function, once the page of data is retrieved from the server, what method(s) would I use in jqGrid to add the page of data, and then properly set paging -- addRowData adds one or more rows -- and if I add 5 rows, how do I tell jqGrid that these 5 records represent page 1 of 10 (something that happens automatically when I use datatype:'json', url:###)? Thanks again.

Comment: The easiest way is *not to use* `datatype` as function. If you can get the data from the server per Ajax call (per `jQuery.ajax` with some parameters which you need) you can just use`datatype: "json"`. jqGrid provides you a lot of customization option to send the option to the server in any way which you prefer. If the data returned from the server almost any data can be read by jqGrid. You need just implement corresponding callbacks which read the information from JSON response. You don't provide any details about the backend which you use and no JSON examples, so I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It was a user error (mine :). I had some show/hide logic in loadComplete of jqGrid, but this event does not fire when addJSONData is called.

addJSONData works just fine when provided with a properly-structured JavaScript object.